# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI - in spring 3.2.4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-mapping

I have this controller:

```
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/manageaccount.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        model.addAllAttributes(getModel(request));

        return "registerAccountView";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/saveaccount.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveaccount(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        model.addAllAttributes(getModel(request));

        return "registerAccountView";
    }
...
```

The controller its mapping well when I put this URL in the browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/accounts/manageaccount.do
```

Then I have this jsp

```
<form method="post" action="saveaccount.do">
</form>
```

But when I submit I got this strange error

```
URL: /devices/accounts/saveaccount.do
???error404.error???
```

Comment: Could you paste the url of the page where is the form and your web.xml file, please ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/accounts/manageaccount.do

Comment: I've tried as well with @RequestMapping("/accounts") with the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the servlet mapping in your web-xml is configured to handle the `.do` requests :

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>yourServletName</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada what is the name of your war file ?

Comment: devices_admin is the name of the war file

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada then your URL should be :  `127.0.0.1:7001/devices_admin/accounts/manageaccount.do ` or change the name of the folder under webapps to devices

Comment: It's deployed in a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0, not in a TOMCAT

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada look for the name of your application in your server